# eReviewBoard can't raise review request

Tags: eclipse, subclipse, review-board

I have my `reviewboard 1.7` configured and I am using `eReviewBoard` and `Subclipse` plugins in `Eclipse IDE`.

The issue is when I try to raise the review request it fails giving "timed out" as **`"Failed creating new review request : Exception executing PutMethod on http://10.203.3.244/api/review-requests/380/draft/ : Read timed out"`**

When I checked the info at `"http://10.203.3.244/api/review-requests/380"` I can't find the `PUT` method for `"http://10.203.3.244/api/review-requests/380/draft"` instead it is only for `"http://10.203.3.244/api/review-requests/380"`

Below is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<rsp>
<stat>ok</stat>
<review_request>
<status>pending</status>
<last_updated>2014-01-22T07:38:34Z</last_updated>
<description>Testing... </description>
<links>
<diffs>
<href>http://10.203.3.244/api/review-requests/380/diffs/</href>
<method>GET</method>
</diffs>
<repository>
<href>http://10.203.3.244/api/repositories/3/</href>
<method>GET</method>
<title>M2M Repository</title>
</repository>
<screenshots>
<href>http://10.203.3.244/api/review-requests/380/screenshots/</href>
<method>GET</method>
</screenshots>
<self>
<href>http://10.203.3.244/api/review-requests/380/</href>
<method>GET</method>
</self>
<update>
<href>http://10.203.3.244/api/review-requests/380/</href>
<method>PUT</method>
</update>
<last_update>
<href>http://10.203.3.244/api/review-requests/380/last-update/</href>
<method>GET</method>
</last_update>
<reviews>
<href>http://10.203.3.244/api/review-requests/380/reviews/</href>
<method>GET</method>
</reviews>
<draft>
<href>http://10.203.3.244/api/review-requests/380/draft/</href>
<method>GET</method>
</draft>
<file_attachments>
<href>http://10.203.3.244/api/review-requests/380/file-attachments/</href>
<method>GET</method>
</file_attachments>
<submitter>
<href>http://10.203.3.244/api/users/amritpal/</href>
<method>GET</method>
<title>amritpal</title>
</submitter>
<changes>
<href>http://10.203.3.244/api/review-requests/380/changes/</href>
<method>GET</method>
</changes>
<delete>
<href>http://10.203.3.244/api/review-requests/380/</href>
<method>DELETE</method>
</delete>
</links>
```

I don't know what to do next. I understand this info is generated and read by the plugin itself??!!

Has anyone faced this issue?

Comment: I found the resolution to this issue. This error was reported due to the incorrect mail server configuration in the RB server. This was corrected and RB was working normally. Thanks anyway Mark! :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you raised this issue with the project, which is what I was going to recommend you do:

https://github.com/rombert/ereviewboard/issues/129